# Monitoring Solr using Monit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr, monitoring, monit

I'm new to Solr and Monit. I have a Rails 3.2 app with Solr, how do you configure monit to handle Solr?

Cheers, and Thanks,
Zeck

Answer (score 0):

To handle solr using monit you need to config it in the monitrc file which is present in /etc/monit/ directory.

Go to the directory

1) cd /etc/monit

and edit the monitrc file using sudo.

2) sudo nano monitrc

At the end of the file past the code given in the link

https://gist.github.com/SammyLin/cc367a8a2fe552bcbb1f

Save the file and reload the monit using

3) sudo monit reload

Now monit will take care of the solr.